# How to add text or water mark on camera image in phonegap cordova

Tags: javascript, timestamp, html5-canvas, phonegap-plugins

Add text or water mark on camera image in phonegap cordova.
Here we want to add time and location on image.
Which cordova plugin can do this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be like this:

Put the image you captured through cordova camera plugin in a canvas tag of HTML instead of img tag.

Canvas tag allows you to draw anything or write any text on the image.

So you can use date() function of JavaScript to get current date time and put that in the form of text on the canvas tag hence over the image.

Hope it helps.